# prevent video with max-width jumping onload

Tags: css, video, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to precent a video from jumping when it loads, I have applied this aspect ratio padding trick which works fine, but not when the video requires a max-width, the padding applied seems too much and never fits correctly. Any ideas?

Reference links:
https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/
https://itnext.io/how-to-stop-content-jumping-when-images-load-7c915e47f576

```
.video-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(675 / 1200 * 100%);
}

#tutorial-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
  width:100%;
  height: auto; 
}

<div class="video-wrap">
  <video id="tutorial-video" width="100%" poster="/assets/video-poster.jpg" autoplay loop playsinline>
    <source src="/videos/tutorial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ko1L84b5/2/

Comment: Can you provide a live example to fiddle with?

Comment: @J.T.Houtenbos Ok added one thanks

Comment: I do not see it jumping in your example - and there is not really a video in your example. Just a video element with a phony source.